# What causes an 'Address already in use' error when executing the bin/setup-cluster command for a Fredhopper installation?

Tags: 2013, fredhopper, linux

I am facing an error while executing bin/setup-cluster for a Fredhopper installation on a Linux box.
Below is the detail for error:

> [fredhopper@ip-10-120-11-163 fredhopper]$ sudo bin/setup-cluster
>   [fredhopper@ip-10-120-11-163 fredhopper]$ grep "ERROR"
>   data/log/agent.log data/instances/deployment/log/kitchen.log
>   data/log/agent.log:2015-09-24 04:26:55,789 ERROR
>   java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Main.java:269)

I am using the dedicated user "fredhopper" for executing commands.

A am using Fredhopper version fredhopper-7.5-revision-13.zip and Smarttarget2014sp1 with Tridion 2013 Sp1.

Answer (score 6):

> java.net.BindException: Address already in use

This means that you are trying to bind to a port which is already in use by another process

Try using `lsof -i:<port>` to determine which process is already bound to the ports that fredhopper is trying to use

FredHopper typically uses ports starting from 8180 and rising by 1000 each time, e.g. 8180, 9180, 10180, 11180, and 12180

By the way, I'm not sure that you're using your dedicated fredhopper user correctly, as you're executing bin/setup-cluster using sudo. This means you are elevating your privileges and executing the process as root, e.g:

> david@davidforster:~$ whoami
>
> david
>
> david@davidforster:~$ sudo whoami
>
> root

Check the online documentation and make sure that it does specify to run that command using sudo

Comment: I haven't mention any port number in my configuration. And in error i am not getting which port is conflicting. So not sure where it is conflicting.

Comment: I executed the command without using sudo, but now i am getting Invoke Failed error while executing `[fredhopper@ip-10-120-11-163 fredhopper]$ bin/setup-cluster
Invoke failed
`

Answer (score 5):

As David mentioned, one or more of the ports are already in use by some other process. So you can try to find out what that is and change its port.

Or you could just use a different "preset" for your instances in topology.txt. The presets define all of the ports for the different Fredhopper services. So for instance, the Query Server for preset 1 uses port 8180. The one for preset 2 uses port 9180. Preset 3 is 10080, and so on.

For more information, check out the [Ports in use by Fredhopper](https://www.fredhopper.com/learningcenter/display/learningcenter/Ports+in+use+by+Fredhopper) page on the FH Learning Center.